# Mysql select from a table and insert into another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a mysql table called jos_users_quizzes with the following columns:

```
id
quiz_id
user_id

I have a second table called  jos_users with this columns


id 
name
username
department
```

the user_id on first table is linked with the id of second table so 
quiz_id = id (jos_users)

How can build a query to multiple insert the ids of a selected department into the jos_users_quizzes table... in one click

I am thinking meabe a sub query or a loop, but no sure how.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What will the value of `quiz_id` be?

Comment: You tagged the question both `mysql` and `sql-server` Which is it?

Comment: is mysql sorry for the misundertanding

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT jos_users_quizzes (quiz_id, user_id)
SELECT $quizID, id
FROM jos_users
WHERE department = 'selected department'
```

Comment: the quiz_id would be selected from a dropdown list from another table which holds all quizzes names and ids

Comment: @tonyr That is the SQL query syntax, replace `$quizID` with the id from the get/post

Comment: the problem is that I need to select all user ids from selected department. For example have a list of departments, and once the department is selected , select all ids pertaining that department and insert all the Ids into the other table (quizid , (alldepartment ids)

Comment: I need a solution as @Tony77 asked. I need to insert data from other table but considering different user id for all users

Answer (score 0):

With [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html), you can quickly insert many rows into a table from one or many tables. For example

```
INSERT INTO jos_users_quizzes (quiz_id)
  SELECT jos_users.id
  FROM jos_users WHERE jos_users.department = 100;
```

Comment: I need to insert both the quiz_id and the users_id, the problem is that I need to select all user ids from selected department